# jquery working only first item when another items was hidden

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I wrote a jquery for show more and show less item. It works fine only for first item. But when I am going another item and select to show more item. It's not working. I understand that when I am switching another item then jquery load and display: hide previous section and display: block corrent section. That's why my jquery not working on for hidden section. Can anyone help me to solve this problem, please?
Thanks.

This is my Code.

```
 var item_length = $('.button_img_custom_class .buttonSelectionItemContainer .ButtonSelectorItem').length;
    var target = $('.button_img_custom_class .buttonSelectionItemContainer');
    $(target).each(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("example");
        var items = $(this).children().length;
    
        if (items > 6) {
            $(this).css({'max-height': '115px', 'overflow': 'hidden'});
            $(this).after('<a id="show-more">Show More</a>');
        }
        ;
    })
    $('#show-more').click(function () {
        if ($(this).prev().hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).prev().removeClass('open');
            $('#show-more').html('Show More');
            $(this).prev().css({'max-height': '115px'});
        } else {
            $(this).prev().addClass('open');
            $('#show-more').html('Show Less');
            $(this).prev().css({'max-height': '1000px'});
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this in a loop:

```
$(this).after('<a id="show-more">Show More</a>');
```

Which means you're creating *multiple* elements with the same `id`, which is invalid.

> It works fine only for first item.

Because there's no reason for jQuery, JavaScript, the browser, etc. to ever look for another `#show-more` element once it's found the element with that `id`.  There shouldn't be another one.

Instead of an `id`, use a `class`:

```
$(this).after('<a class="show-more">Show More</a>');
```

And bind the click handler to that class:

```
$('.show-more').click(function () {
    if ($(this).prev().hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).prev().removeClass('open');
        $(this).html('Show More');
        $(this).prev().css({'max-height': '115px'});
    } else {
        $(this).prev().addClass('open');
        $(this).html('Show Less');
        $(this).prev().css({'max-height': '1000px'});
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much your Quick response and great help. Thanks a lot.